# Grep Multiple string search- sorting output

Tags: grep

here is my code

```
iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -w "ESSID\|Quality"
```

it returns

```
                Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm
                ESSID:"NETGEAR00"
                Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm
                ESSID:"dlink_test"
                Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
                ESSID:""
                Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm
                ESSID:"linksys"
                Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm
```

I would like to sort it by the ESSID first, followed by the Quality level on the same line.

```
ESSID:"NETGEAR00"                  Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm
```

Any suggestions?  Linux Newb!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't want to *sort*, but to simply join pairs of lines (the second before the first).  Try:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -w "ESSID\|Quality" | tac | sed '$!N;s/\n/\t/'
```

For the given input, it would yield:

```
ESSID:"linksys" Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm
ESSID:""    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
ESSID:"dlink_test"  Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm
ESSID:"NETGEAR00"   Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm
```

Comment: I received an error message ./wifiscan: line 5: tac: command not found.

Comment: Instead of `tac`, say `sed '1!G;h;$!d'`